# unix application hangs during fread() when sending SIGINT

Tags: c++, c, unix, fread

I'm reading a big file using fread. When I interrupt the program during it using Ctrl+C, the program hangs and is not killable, also not with kill -9. It simple sticks with 100% CPU, keeping the RAM it had already allocated. It would be great to get that fixed, but it would also be okay just to be able to kill that application from outside (the main problem being the fact that I can't restart that machine myself). 
Is there a way of doing that in Unix?

Thanks!

Here is the source:

```
int Read_New_Format(const char* prefix,const char* folder)
{
  char filename[500];
  long count_pos;
  //open files for reading. 
  sprintf(filename,"%s/%s.pos.mnc++",folder,prefix);
  FILE *pos = fopen(filename,"r");
  if(pos==NULL)
  {
    printf("Could not open pos file %s\n",filename);


  }

  //read the number count of entries in each of the three files.
   fread(&count_pos,sizeof(long),1,pos);


  printf("[...]");

  //read the complete file into an array.

  float *data_pos = new float[3*count_pos];



  fread(data_pos,3*sizeof(float),*count_pos,pos);

  printf("Read files.\n");
[...]
}
```

Comment: Are you really talking about *the* Unix, or some unix like OS? In most unix like OSs, processes that are struck in certain system calls can not be killed, even with -9.

Comment: Can you post the source code ? Normally the signal will interrrupt the system call.

Comment: I added the source code. I figured out that my own system here does react on the signal... and I found that using open() and read() on the remote machine instead of fopen/fread works.

Comment: `fread(data_pos,3*sizeof(float),*count_pos,pos);`
should be : `fread(data_pos,3*sizeof(float),count_pos,pos);
`. Typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem wasn't reproducable after some days. Maybe a problem with the file system. As a workaround, direct use of the unix library routines instead of fread worked.

Answer (score 1):

If your program cannot be interrupted by a signal, that almost surely means it's in an uninterruptable sleep state. This is normally an extremely short-lived state that only exists momentarily while waiting for the physical disk to perform a read or write, either due to an explicit `read` or `write` call that can't be satisfied by the cache, or one resulting from a page fault where a disk-backed page is not swapped into physical memory.

If the uninterruptable sleep state persists, this is almost surely indicative of either extremely high load on the storage device (a huge number of IO requests all happening at once) or, much more likely, damaged hardware.

I suspect you have a failing hard disk or scratched optical disc.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I don't believe it's the hardware or I/O load because beside this problem, the system is running well and is used by quite a lot of other people who don't have this problem. Also (but this might be misleading) top tells me that the process is running and not sleeping (S) or uninterruptable sleeping(D). As I mentioned above, the problem does not occur when using read instead of fread. I will try if it has to do with my compiler on that machine and post here again.

Comment: Have you installed a signal handler or modified the signal mask?

Comment: This behavior is very strange then. Perhaps you could attach `strace` to your running program and tell us what happens when you hit ctrl-c? (Don't run it under `strace` to begin with though or `strace` itself will get the `SIGINT` and exit...)

Comment: I tried that and figured out that I can not reproduce the problem anymore. Maybe you were right and it was a problem with the file system or something similar. Thanks!